# Preload or postload a text file for autocomplete jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to add an autocomplete implemented in jquery and my list of suggestions is approximately 300-400 key value pairs. About 15-20 kb total file size.

Since the list is not going to change often, i was thinking of including the text file of the list on the page load footer with script tag and setting an expires header of around 30 days.

But the list is only going to be used when a person uses autocomplete on the website which is around 1 in 20 users.

Do you think there is a better way to get the near real time response for autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is jQuery just use [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to load the script. That way the script will not slow down the page load, but will always be available as soon as possible. If you set it to be cached, the penalty should not be significant. If you add a version number to the file name, you can set the expire to never...

Comment: So what you mean is instead of `<script src="//www.xyz.com/data/data.txt"></script>`, i should be using jQuery.ready() to load a script.
Is there any better way of doing this. Like only load the data file after 1-2 seconds of page load, becase 99% Of the times, User will only use the search after atleast 1-2 seconds. or some other better way of solving this problem ?

Comment: @SonaliKapoor Yes, you can add a delay, but seriously as long as the user doesn't need to wait for the load (it is asynchronous and done after content is loaded) and the script is cached with high expiry it is fine. You could of course trigger load on focus event on the search field. That would avoid all useless loads and usually be fast enough. Fast users would end up waiting though.

Comment: If it is asynchronous and done after content is loaded, i guess this works fine for now. But Can you think of any other way of solving this problem or loading 20k file with the first request sounds ok to you.

Comment: @SonaliKapoor I think it is okay. 20kB loaded once is not too much. Have you minified it and enabled compression? For something like this the size savings are significant. Another issue is the extra request needed, but as long as it comes **after** the requests users need to wait for, it is not a problem. And HTTP/2 will remove even that pain...

Comment: This is after i minified it. Before that it is around 26kb.